# how to make timer for ajax request in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My question is i want to get total time of ajax request..
I means when i click on button then make a ajax request and start timer and store time in button caption,after ajax request success stop timer...

**My problem is**

when i click on button call ajax request and after ajax request successfully then timer start.

**What i want**

I want to start timer before ajax request and stop after ajax request success

**My html code**

```
<input class="btn green start_timer" value="Sync" name="btn" type="button">
```

**My js code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var setTimer = null;
    $("body").on('click', '.start_timer', function () {
        var obj = $(this);
        var start = 1;
        setTimer = setInterval(function () {
            start++;
            obj.val(start);
        }, 1000);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + "timerstart/start/1325",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                clearInterval(setTimer);
            }
        });
        return false
    });
});
```

Comment: move timer script before click event

Comment: no i have 10 checkbox in my local in i want to make ajax request if checkbox checked and store timer in checkbox caption..

Comment: Hi Nikhil, How much time it will taking to complete the total request in your case, your timer will start after 1 sec, if the request takes more than 1 sec, then only your code works

Comment: 10 or 15 second

Comment: Ok i will made a sample request that takes more than 2 secs  and test your code and let you know, thanks

Comment: Nikhil, did u tried with async:true

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

**Steps:**

1. Use [ajaxSend](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) to trigger timer.

   a. Display overlay.
   b. Start the timer function. Use Interval to update timer on every second.
2. Use [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to stop timer.

   a. You can use ClearInterval to stop timer.
3. Calculate the difference incase you want that value to display after overlay is closed.

**Notes:**

1. Note that above mentioned global events will work as expected when there is only one ajax call at any moment of time.
2. You need to use Global variables to get the values from global events and calculate the difference.

Comment: I want TIMER not total TIME.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela: Means? You want something like stopwatch that updates the time spent every second?

Comment: Yeah when i click on button timer start and after ajax request success then stop timer.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela: I guess, you can use the same steps with a little twist for developing a Timer. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: @NikhilVaghela: I have updated the answer. Let me know, if this helps or not.

Comment: I have try this code and it's works if i not call ajax request..But not work if call ajax request

Comment: @NikhilVaghela: Sad :( I cannot think of why this is not working when you are using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

try this below updated:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var setTimer = null;
        $("body").on('click', '.start_timer', function () {
            StartDispalyingTimer($(this));
        });
        RunAjax = function (ele){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async:true,
                url: "index2.php",
                success: function (data) {clearInterval(setTimer);},
                error: function (data) {clearInterval(setTimer);}
            });
        }
        StartDispalyingTimer = function (ele){var start = 1;
            setTimer = setInterval(function () {start++;ele.val((start-1));}, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){RunAjax(ele);},1000);
        }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: In your code timer start after ajax request success.So not working

Comment: get same output ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var setTimer = null;

    $("body").on('click', '.start_timer', function () {
        var element = $(this);
        displayTimer(element);
    });

    function getData(element){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async:true,
            url: "",
            success: function (data) {
               clearInterval(setTimer);
               element.val("Sync");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                 clearInterval(setTimer);
                 element.val("Sync");
            }
        });
    }


    function displayTimer(element){
        var start = 1;
        setTimer = setInterval(function () {
            start++;
            element.val(start);
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function(){
            getData(element);
        },2000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got `async=false` in the options for your ajax request. This makes your request synchronous so the execution of the script "hangs" untill the request comes back with a response. You should never use async is false.